# Pandas Dataframe forward fill upto certain condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe like this generated from the below code: [df1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug4nV.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [True, '-', '-', '-', True, '-', '-', '-', True, '-', '-', '-'], 
                   'End': ['-', '-', '-', True, '-', '-', '-', True, '-', '-', '-', True], 
                   'Value': ['-', 15, '-', '-', 109, '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', 13, '-']})
df

|       | Start |  End  | Value |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     0 |  True |     - |     - |
|     1 |     - |     - |    15 |
|     2 |     - |     - |     - |
|     3 |     - |  True |     - |
|     4 |  True |     - |   109 |
|     5 |     - |     - |     - |
|     6 |     - |     - |     - |
|     7 |     - |  True |     - |
|     8 |  True |     - |     - |
|     9 |     - |     - |     - |
|    10 |     - |     - |    13 |
|    11 |     - |  True |     - |
```

and I would like to forward fill the 'Value' column till the point where 'End' column == True like this: [df2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kw1oy.png)

```
|       | Start |  End  | Value |
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
|     0 |  True |     - |     - |
|     1 |     - |     - |    15 |
|     2 |     - |     - |    15 |
|     3 |     - |  True |    15 |
|     4 |  True |     - |   109 |
|     5 |     - |     - |   109 |
|     6 |     - |     - |   109 |
|     7 |     - |  True |   109 |
|     8 |  True |     - |     - |
|     9 |     - |     - |     - |
|    10 |     - |     - |    13 |
|    11 |     - |  True |    13 |
```

Any help will be highly appreaciated!

PS.  Sorry my reputation is not high enough to post images directly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, always avoid to have mixed types in a column. Apparently you have strings and boolean values - that's not recommended.

First, make your data frame workable:

```
df = df.replace('-',np.nan).astype(float)
```

Then, simple `groupby`+`ffill`

```
s = df.start.eq(1).cumsum()
df['value'] = df.groupby(s).value.ffill()
```

---

```
    start  end  value
0     1.0  NaN    NaN
1     NaN  NaN   15.0
2     NaN  NaN   15.0
3     NaN  1.0   15.0
4     1.0  NaN  109.0
5     NaN  NaN  109.0
6     NaN  NaN  109.0
7     NaN  1.0  109.0
8     1.0  NaN    NaN
9     NaN  NaN    NaN
10    NaN  NaN   13.0
11    NaN  1.0   13.0
```

Comment: I know I'm commenting on an old answer here, but this was extremely helpful for a problem I've been trying to solve. Thank you.